# 3 Tag Badges are mentioned on both Earned and Unearned Badges pages

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow, badges, help-center

On both lists [Earned Badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=general&filter=earned) and [Unearned badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=general&filter=unearned) I can see 3 equal badges:

```
Bronze Badge You must have a total score of 100 in at least 20 non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge. 43.9k awarded
Silver Badge You must have a total score of 400 in at least 80 non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge. 7.8k awarded
Gold Badge You must have a total score of 1000 in at least 200 non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge. 2.3k awarded
```

The only difference in a green tick to the left of each.

Comment: Those are tag badges and it means you earned at least one of each kind. Good job, and it's not a bug

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: Will a section disappear when you have no earned or have earned all of them? For me I have this section on each page what misleads me.

Comment: Just tested it on other site where I don't have tag badges, and the section appears in the "earned" tab but empty.

Comment: It's on both because you have earned the badges on some tags but not on all tags.

Comment: @AndrewC: My main concern that this is 0 times obvious.

Answer (score 2):

@AndrewC said in comments:

> It's on both because you have earned the badges on some tags but not on all tags

In my opinion, badges should disappear from the "unearned" category when we have earned it one time. Otherwise, the badge will remain in the category forever, since there's tag creation every day and it's impossible (except for Community ♦ maybe :-) ) to get these badges on every tag.

I approve the author, it's a bug for me.